# How can I see the questions and answers I've voted on?

Tags: support, voting, recent-activity

Often I'll find that I need to find a question I'd recently looked at and voted on, but can't quite remember the title. Since I voted on it, and I can't vote twice, I know there's a record of which questions and answers I've voted on. Is that exposed anywhere?

I guess I'll just be more liberal with marking questions as favorites.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which up-votes you gave on `https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2317/drewish?tab=votes&sort=upvote` and the down-votes you gave on `https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2317/drewish?tab=votes&sort=downvote`.

It has been restored around April 26, 2012, as documented [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/140449) for [Where did the Votes Tab go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go)

> For the time being you can trawl through your downvoted list.
>
> And it is now full fledged. We can see different vote casts.
>
> 1. Upvotes
> 2. Downvotes
> 3. Delete Votes
> 4. Undelete Votes
> 5. Closure Votes
> 6. Reopen Votes
>
> [image: Screenshot of the votes tab]